# Fallback to html5 video if flash is not available

Tags: html5-video, flash, flowplayer

Currently the desktop version of my site uses flash player ( flowplayer) to stream videos.I would like to have a fallback to html5 just in case flash isn't available

So in case flash is not available , html5 should be used by default and the video **should** **autoplay**

I tried the following code but **both** flowplayer and html5 seems to load the video at the same time.I noticed that when i pause the video(playing with flowplayer) , i can still hear the video, implying that html5 player is loading the video as well.

```
<object id="flowplayer" width="640" height="360" data="./flowplayer-3.2.18.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
 <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
 <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
  <param name="flashvars" value=\'config={"clip":"./test.mp4", "plugins": {"controls": {"autoHide" : false} }}\' />
 <video width="100%" height="100%" controls preload autoplay>  
  <source src="./test.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> 
 </video>
</object>
```

Any help is appreciated